# How to get indices of non-diagonal elements of a numpy array?

Tags: python, numpy

How to get indices of non-diagonal elements of a numpy array?

```
a = np.array([[7412, 33, 2],
              [2, 7304, 83],
              [3, 101, 7237]])
```

I tried as follows:

```
diag_indices = np.diag_indices_from(a)
print diag_indices
(array([0, 1, 2], dtype=int64), array([0, 1, 2], dtype=int64))
```

After that, no idea...
The expected result should be:

```
result = [[False, True, True],
        [True, False, True],
         [True, True, False]]
```

Answer (score 28, accepted):

To get the mask, you can use [`np.eye`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.1/reference/generated/numpy.eye.html), like so -

```
~np.eye(a.shape[0],dtype=bool)
```

To get the indices, add [`np.where`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.1/reference/generated/numpy.where.html) -

```
np.where(~np.eye(a.shape[0],dtype=bool))
```

Sample run -

```
In [142]: a
Out[142]: 
array([[7412,   33,    2],
       [   2, 7304,   83],
       [   3,  101, 7237]])

In [143]: ~np.eye(a.shape[0],dtype=bool)
Out[143]: 
array([[False,  True,  True],
       [ True, False,  True],
       [ True,  True, False]], dtype=bool)

In [144]: np.where(~np.eye(a.shape[0],dtype=bool))
Out[144]: (array([0, 0, 1, 1, 2, 2]), array([1, 2, 0, 2, 0, 1]))
```

---

There are few more ways to get such a mask for a generic *non-square* input array.

With [`np.fill_diagonal`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.0/reference/generated/numpy.fill_diagonal.html) -

```
out = np.ones(a.shape,dtype=bool)
np.fill_diagonal(out,0)
```

With [`broadcasting`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/basics.broadcasting.html) -

```
m,n = a.shape
out = np.arange(m)[:,None] != np.arange(n)
```

Comment: why a.shape[0] instead of a?

Comment: @gudlife Because `np.eye()` accepts shape parameter to create such a 2D array.

Answer (score 2):

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> a = np.array([[7412, 33, 2],
...               [2, 7304, 83],
...               [3, 101, 7237]])
>>> non_diag = np.ones(shape=a.shape, dtype=bool) - np.identity(len(a)).astype(bool)
>>> non_diag
array([[False,  True,  True],
       [ True, False,  True],
       [ True,  True, False]], dtype=bool)
```

Comment: In the current version of numpy, I get `TypeError: numpy boolean subtract, the '-' operator, is not supported, use the bitwise_xor, the '^' operator, or the logical_xor function instead.`

Comment: This works: `nonDiag = (np.ones(shape=a.shape) - np.identity(len(a))).astype(bool)`

Answer (score 0):

As an additional idea to previous answers, you could select the indices of the *upper* and *lower triangles*:

```
a = np.array([[7412, 33, 2],
              [2, 7304, 83],
              [3, 101, 7237]])
# upper triangle. k=1 excludes the diagonal elements.
xu, yu = np.triu_indices_from(a, k=1)
# lower triangle
xl, yl = np.tril_indices_from(a, k=-1)  # Careful, here the offset is -1

# combine
x = np.concatenate((xl, xu))
y = np.concatenate((yl, yu))
```

As described in the [doc](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.triu_indices.html), you can then use those to index and assign values:

```
out = np.ones((3,3), dtype=bool)
out[(x, y)] = False
```

gives:

```
>>> out
array([[ True, False, False],
   [False,  True, False],
   [False, False,  True]])
```

Answer (score 0):

To extend @PlasmaBinturong's and @Divakar's answers, you could use advanced indexing based on `np.triu_indices` and `np.tril_indices`:

```
triu_idx = np.triu_indices(len(a), k=1) #finding advanced indices of upper right triangle
tril_idx = np.tril_indices(len(a), k=-1) #finding advanced indices of lower left triangle
out = np.ones(a.shape, dtype=bool)
out[triu_idx] = False #padding upper right triangle with zeros
out[tril_idx] = False #padding upper left triangle with zeros
>>> out
array([[ True, False, False],
       [False,  True, False],
       [False, False,  True]])
```

- `triu_idx = np.triu_indices(len(a), k=1)` is a shorthand for `np.nonzero(np.less.outer(np.arange(len(a)), np.arange(len(a))))`
- `np.tril_indices(len(a), k=-1)` is a shorthand for
  `np.nonzero(np.greater.outer(np.arange(len(a)), np.arange(len(a))))`

So instead of `np.less.outer(...)` & `np.greater.outer(...)` you could use:

```
>>> np.not_equal.outer(np.arange(len(a)), np.arange(len(a)))
array([[False,  True,  True],
       [ True, False,  True],
       [ True,  True, False]])
```

which could be replaced by Syntactic Sugar in @Divakar's solution: `np.arange(len(a))[:, None] != np.arange(len(a))`

This is an output desired but besides that, let's plug it into a previous code to compare with the previous process:

```
out = np.ones(a.shape, dtype=bool)
idx = np.not_equal.outer(np.arange(len(a)), np.arange(len(a))) # you need only this
tri_both = np.nonzero(idx)
out[tri_both] = False
>>> out
array([[False,  True,  True],
       [ True, False,  True],
       [ True,  True, False]])
```

**Conclusion**. Don't convert boolean indices to numerical ones and then back. This is inefficient as to compare with working on boolean indices straight.

Answer (score 0):

```
import numpy as np
a = np.array([[7412, 33, 2],
              [2, 7304, 83],
              [3, 101, 7237]])
np.invert(np.eye(a.shape[0], dtype=bool))
```

gives

```
array([[False,  True,  True],
       [ True, False,  True],
       [ True,  True, False]])
```

When a Boolean diagonal matrix is inverted, off-diagonal terms become True while the diagonal terms are False.