# Python: Obtain a matrix containing all differences between all elements from another matrix

Tags: python, numpy, matrix

I need to calculate all differences (in absolute value) between all combinations of the elements from a given matrix. For example, given some matrix `M` such as

```
M = [[1 2]
 [5 8]]
```

I need to obtain a matrix `X` defined as

```
X = [[1 4 7]
[1, 3, 6]
[4, 3, 3]
[7, 6, 3]]
```

where I associated each row to each element in `M` and each column with its substraction from every other element (except with itself). I've been trying to make some `for` cicles, but I haven't been able to get something close to what I want.

In my code, I used numpy, thus defining all the matrices as

```
M = np.zeros([nx, ny])
```

and then replacing the values as the code progresses such as

```
M[i, j] = 5
```

Answer (score 1):

While this can be easily done by looping over elements, here is a faster and more pythonic way.

```
import numpy as np

M = np.array([[1,2],[5,8]])

# flatten M matrix
flatM = M.reshape(-1) 

# get all pairwise differences
X = flatM[:,None] - flatM[None,:]

# remove diagonal elements, since you don't want differences between same elements
mask = np.where(~np.eye(X.shape[0],dtype=bool))
X = X[mask]

# reshape X into desired form
X = X.reshape(len(flatM),-1)

# take absolute values
X = np.abs(X)

print(X)
```

Removal of diagonal elements was done using approach suggested here [How to get indices of non-diagonal elements of a numpy array?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35746806/how-to-get-indices-of-non-diagonal-elements-of-a-numpy-array)

Answer (score 0):

Sensibly the same approach as the very good answer of @wizzzz1, but with a simpler syntax and faster execution:

```
a = M.ravel()
X = (abs(a-a[:, None])
     [~np.eye(M.size, dtype=bool)]
     .reshape(-1, M.size-1)
     )
```

Output:

```
array([[1, 4, 7],
       [1, 3, 6],
       [4, 3, 3],
       [7, 6, 3]])
```